# How to integral : (1-i) / cosh z on C

Tags: complex-analysis

Let C be the triangular contour connecting 3i, -1-i, 1-i.
How to interal (1-i) / cosh z on C ?
Don't use the residue theorem..

Comment: Do you kow the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\cosh(z)}$

Comment: It has a problem at (pi)i/2. Has the antiderivative a meaning ?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do it by antidifferentiation, but you have to be careful and you will need to split the integral into two parts.  First, let
$$w=i\log\frac{1-ie^z}{1+ie^z}\ .$$
You can easily check that as long as $w$ is analytic, it is an antiderivative of $1/\cosh z$.

So, where is $w$ analytic?  It depends on which branch of the logarithm we take.  First choose
$$\log z=\log(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta\ ,\quad -\pi<\theta\le\pi\ .$$
This is analytic except for $z=-a$, where $a$ is real and $a\ge0$.  This means that the points at which $w$ is not analytic are given by
$$\frac{1-ie^z}{1+ie^z}=-a\ ;$$
if my algebra is correct (better check it!) this leads to
$$e^z=i\frac{a+1}{a-1}=ib$$
with $b$ real and $|b|\ge1$, and hence $z=x+iy$ where
$$x\ge0\ ,\quad y=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\ .$$
If you draw these $z$ values in the complex plane you will see that your path of integration from $3i$ to $-1-i$ to $1-i$ avoids them, so you can evaluate this part of the integral as
$$(1-i)\bigl(w(1-i)-w(3i)\bigr)\ .$$

Now take the branch of the logarithm given by
$$\log z=\log(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta\ ,\quad 0\le\theta<2\pi$$
and do similar calculations.  If I haven't slipped up you get $w$ analytic except for
$$x\le0\ ,\quad y=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\ ,$$
and this enables you to evaluate the integral along the third side of the triangle.

. . . and after doing all that, you will **really** appreciate the method of residues ;-)

Comment: It's not coshz, but 1/coshz. Am I misunderstanding your proof?

Comment: No, it was just a typo in the answer, fixed now, apologies.